# IE10 looking for commented out javascript method

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a web app running in ie10 and a user has just reported the following problem (Just curious, why would an error message generated by Internet Explorer say "User Agent:  Mozilla/4.0" ?):

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;     
Trident/6.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 
3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)

Timestamp: Thu, 18 Jun 2015 21:56:43 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support property or method 'iAmCommentedOut'
Line: 42
Char: 9
Code: 0
URI: http://some.server/dir1/dir2/script1.js
```

Which seems pretty straightforward.

Until I look at the code and find that the only place iAmCommentedOut occurs is as a string in a log message and in a *comment*

It was a javascript method used in a previous version of the app.

In the current version, it has been removed

script2.js

```
/*self.iAmAlsoCommentedOut = function(){
    do other stuff
};
self.iAmCommentedOut = function(){
    do some stuff
};*/
```

script2.js does contain other, non commented out methods AND the object defined in script2.js is instantiated and used in script1.js

So they are related.

However I cannot duplicate this.  When I run the same app from the same server on the same OS (Windows 7) using the same browser (IE10) the error does not occur.

What on earth could cause this behavior?

(FYI i'm using jQuery 1.4.3)

Comment: For the UA strings: http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/

Comment: the user agent `MSIE 7.0` suggests the browser is ie7, not 10, that might be why you can't replicate it

Comment: @reg4in - are you serious?  its all a shell game?

Comment: i guess that article is somewhat ironical but yea that is about it

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a problem with a cached version of some other script being used.

Comment: yes, there was a similar problem earlier in the week.  a user had a slightly less mysterious error in scriptA.js.  despite clearing the cache from Tools | Internet Options in IE the only way the problem with scriptA.js went away was to open its url http://some.server/dir1/dir2/scriptA.js directly in the browser.  why is that necessary?